# How to reverse a fnv1a_64 hashed value?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

**declare denyClasses**

```
private long[] denyClasses = {
                    4165360493669296979L,
                    4446674157046724083L
            };
```

**use denyClasses**

```
String className = clazz.getName();
long hashCode64 = TypeUtils.fnv1a_64(className);
if (Arrays.binarySearch(denyClasses, hashCode64) >= 0) {
    throw new JSONException("not support class : " + className);
}
```

**declare fnv1a_64**

```
public static long fnv1a_64(String key){
        long hashCode = 0xcbf29ce484222325L;
        for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); ++i){
            char ch = key.charAt(i);
            hashCode ^= ch;
            hashCode *= 0x100000001b3L;
        }
        return hashCode;
    }
```

What is the corresponding string of 4165360493669296979L?

What is the corresponding string of 4446674157046724083L?

How do you compute that?

Comment: Hash functions are supposed to be _one-way functions_, so there is no easy way to get back the input, given the output.

Comment: There can't be so many classes that it's infeasible to do a brute-force search, though. You can do it by testing the name of every class in your classpath.

Comment: For each hash value, there are uncountably many strings with that hash.  It's not so hard to find one, but it won't be a class name.

Comment: Hash functions are not easily reversible. But if the hashing function is done without any salt, as in your question, a rainbow table can be used to reverse lookup values within the bounds of the table. Just for fun I tried your values, but had no luck - they must have too many characters.